# Code in async function executed twice when called from React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my minimal code to show the issue:

```
async function doSomeThings(caller) {
  console.log('Step 1 for ' + caller);
  await 1;
  console.log('Step 2 for ' + caller);
}

function TestAsyncComponent() {
  doSomeThings('React component');
  return null;
}

doSomeThings('module');

export default TestAsyncComponent;
```

The `TestAsyncComponent` is simply rendered inside of a page. The code that does that is essentially just the boilerplate generated by create-react-app. But if you want to see it, I'll drag it in.

When `TestAsyncComponent` is imported and then rendered, console output shows the following:

```
Step 1 for module
Step 2 for module
Step 1 for React component
Step 2 for React component
Step 2 for React component
```

There is something about calling the async function from the React function during rendering that causes a portion of the code inside the async function to execute twice. That's totally unexpected to me.

Note - the *async function* isn't called twice. If that were the case, then "Step 1 for React component" would be output twice. Execution occurs twice for the code after the "await 1" statement within the async function.

How do I prevent this called-twice-from-React behavior? Also, I'm very interested in the explanation of why the code after "await 1" is called twice.

Comment: in the console output, on the line that shows `Step 1 for React component`, is there an indication that this has been logged twice? I know firefox can "merge" duplicate sequential log outputs (and indicates it with a (2) or (3) etc on the right hand side of the output)- not sure abut whatever browser you're using

Comment: e.g. `for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {console.log(i>>1);}` logs 0 1 2 3 4 on separate lines, not 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 ... note: when directly run in console, 0 0 1 1 2 2 etc is logged, so this "compression" of identical logs only happens when script in the page is logged, not when run directly in console

Comment: React can execute function components multiple times for arbitrary reasons, and in some cases squelches console output for those duplicate calls, as it's just that common of a "benign side-effect" to use. It cannot do so, if it is async (remember, async functions run sync until the first `await`, therefore the first log is still inside react's reach).

Comment: To elaborate: ["Starting with React 17, React automatically modifies the console methods like console.log() to silence the logs in the second call to lifecycle functions"](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) (no id to jump to, need to search/scroll), and i'd guess that's what mutes the duplicate for "1", but not for "2", as it cannot affect that.

Comment: @ASDFGerte - wow! A trap for young players right there

Comment: Wouldn't putting this in a useEffect stop this?

Comment: Note that i am not absolutely sure here, but with the given information, this seems the most likely cause. Generally, you should never have side-effects inside render calls, that's what `useEffect` or similar are for. See [rules of react](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#rules-of-react-rendering) (PS: if you are new, i'd suggest reading that article from start to finish, at least i found it very informative - although i think it doesn't cover the newest react features, e.g. concurrent mode)

Comment: A useEffect will fix this, also, the code included is not valid JSX. `useEffect(()=> {
    doSomeThings('module');
  }, [])`

Comment: If you put breakpoints at `console.log('Step 1 for ' + caller);` and `console.log('Step 2 for ' + caller);` you'll see that _both_ of them get triggered twice with `caller === 'React component'`, and if you put a breakpoint in `TestAsyncComponent`, you'll see that it is rendered twice. React works in mysterious ways 

Comment: Re "compression" (@Bravo), yes, I was taking the compression of identical logs into account. Good thing to check, though.

Comment: Re "squelches console input" (@ASDFGerte), yes! With breakpoints, (@tromgy) I confirmed the async function was actually getting called twice. If React suppressed the console-output as you say, I'm a bit miffed at whoever made that decision.

Comment: Re "useEffect will fix this" (@RolandoYera), in fact, it did. So that would be an answer. The console.log weirdness moved me away from a pretty simple solution. I was imagining stranger things happening with the async code.

Comment: Re "you should never have side-effects inside render calls" (@ASDFGerte) Of course, you're right. I was just trying to contrive the simplest code to show the problem. I like it when questions on SO are like that for knowledge-building reasons.

Comment: @RolandoYera, if you want to write up your "useEffect()" comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's original premise that the async function isn't called twice is incorrect. Console logging was suppressed for one output of the `console.log('Step 1 for ' + caller)` line. But setting a breakpoint in the debugger proved execution came to this line twice instead of once.

The problem can be fixed with `useEffect()` like so:

```
function TestAsyncComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    doSomeThings('React component');
    return null;
  }, []);
}
```

This works because the call to `doSomeThings()` will only be called once.

Self-answering to just have an answer on record for the question. Thanks to those who helped above in comments.